# jquery callbacks and json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to work out how to take my returned json data and add it to my current view.

I have this

controller

```
def rehomed
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render json: @animals }
  end
end
```

view

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/public/rehomed',
  data: data_send,
   success: function(data) {
    $('.all_animals').append(data);
   }
});
```

view

```
 <div class="col-md-4 mix Dog Pontypool all" style="display: inline-block;">
  <a alt="Yorkshire Terrier" href="/animals/91-archibald"></a>
    <div class="title">
      <h5>Archibald</h5>
      <h5><span data-hover="Yorkshire Terrier">Yorkshire Terrier</span></h5>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 mix Dog Pontypool all" style="display: inline-block;">
   <a alt="Yorkshire Terrier" href="/animals/91-archibald" title="Yorkshire Terrier"></a>
    <div class="title">
      <h5>Archibald</h5>
      <h5><span data-hover="Yorkshire Terrier">Yorkshire Terrier</span></h5>
    </div>
 </div>

[
 {"id":104,"animal_type":"Dog","name":"Harry","description":"Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum.","age":"Under 1 Year","size":"Large","gender":"Male","spay_neuter":"No","chipped":"No","child_friendly":"No","reference":"AB123456789","dog_breed_id":2,"user_id":12,"created_at":"2014-10-28T22:07:15.311Z","updated_at":"2014-10-28T22:07:15.311Z","cat_breed_id":null,"rehomed":false},
 {"id":107,"animal_type":"Cat","name":"Sydney","description":"Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum.","age":"Under 1 Year","size":null,"gender":"Female","spay_neuter":"No","chipped":"Yes","child_friendly":null,"reference":"123456","dog_breed_id":null,"user_id":12,"created_at":"2014-10-28T22:08:06.609Z","updated_at":"2014-10-28T22:08:06.609Z","cat_breed_id":1,"rehomed":false},   
 {"id":114,"animal_type":"Cat","name":"Tommy","description":"Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum.","age":"4 Years","size":null,"gender":"Female","spay_neuter":"No","chipped":"Yes","child_friendly":null,"reference":"123856473SS","dog_breed_id":null,"user_id":12,"created_at":"2014-10-28T22:09:20.640Z","updated_at":"2014-10-28T22:09:20.640Z","cat_breed_id":2,"rehomed":false},
 {"id":116,"animal_type":"Cat","name":"Alice","description":"Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum.","age":"Under 1 Year","size":null,"gender":"Female","spay_neuter":"No","chipped":"No","child_friendly":null,"reference":"ghf4584624","dog_breed_id":null,"user_id":12,"created_at":"2014-10-28T22:09:43.956Z","updated_at":"2014-10-28T22:09:43.956Z","cat_breed_id":2,"rehomed":false},
 {"id":124,"animal_type":"Cat","name":"Tommy","description":"Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum.","age":"5 Years","size":null,"gender":"Female","spay_neuter":"Yes","chipped":"No","child_friendly":null,"reference":"ghf4584624","dog_breed_id":null,"user_id":12,"created_at":"2014-10-28T22:11:19.696Z","updated_at":"2014-10-28T22:11:19.696Z","cat_breed_id":2,"rehomed":false},
 {"id":87,"animal_type":"Dog","name":"Chloe","description":"Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum.","age":"5 Years","size":"Small","gender":"Female","spay_neuter":"Yes","chipped":"No","child_friendly":"Yes","reference":"ghf4584624","dog_breed_id":2,"user_id":13,"created_at":"2014-10-28T22:03:57.396Z","updated_at":"2014-10-28T22:03:57.396Z","cat_breed_id":null,"rehomed":false}
 ]
```

How do i take that json data and format it to show in my view like the other records?

Thanks

Comment: `.map` each result in the array to an HTML element.

Comment: if you have a number of different calls to make there are numerous template scripts like handlebars, mustache etc you can use

Answer (score 1):

You will have to parse the json...

Use:

```
var response_array=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
for (response in response_array) {
    id = response.id;
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: no need to use `parseJSON` if you simply set the `dataType:'json'` ...jQuery will return the array

Comment: You mean use it as argument to `$.json`? I didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: actually no need to do either, sorry guys, forgot to put in my controller action

Comment: @RubyRacer no, it is an option for `$.ajax` and can also be passed as argument for `$.get` and `$.post( url, data, callback,'json')`